# django admin how to prevent brute force attack?

Tags: django, django-admin

CAPTHCA/additional table field/allowed ip's - not propose. 
I think best option is: keep login attempts in server cache. 
If you can propound other options or cut up option with cache, you are welcome.

Comment: The easiest way I know to prevent brute force on the admin site is actually to make up a stupid admin URL. Something like www.your-site.com/thisisatotallyhiddenadminurlthatmakesithardertofind

Comment: This method has disadvantages: 1) not userfriendly 2) Chrome, IE, toolbars (like yandex toolbar) for FF sends info about visited site's to search engine's, so with the right search query `thisisatotallyhiddenadminurlthatmakesithardertofind` will disclosed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically I would use the INTERNAL_IPS setting, and make a middleware that blocks access to /admin/ if you're not part of INTERNAL_IPS

Another option is to play with https://github.com/dmpayton/django-admin-honeypot -- you could potentially write a cron job that blocks these IPs via iptables or something.

Comment: As I say in question allowed ip's (INTERNAL_IPS) is a bad idea, because in admin area have access many groups (copywriters, moderators, translators etc) and they can have dynamic ip. About `django-admin-honeypot`: most likely an attack will happen with proxy's usage.

Comment: You can use INTERNAL_IPS and require a VPN.

Comment: is there a way to get INTERNAL_IPS to work when using hosting behind a reverse proxy? Like a gunicorn & Nginx setup

Comment: Yup. then it's not REMOTE_ADDR that you're looking for, typically for me, it's X_FORWARDED_FOR. Here's what it looks like for me https://gist.github.com/6980d4a2e1bf7d1919c5

Comment: @cevter: About django-admin-honeypot: you mean IP blocking will be too restrictive?